# Как изменить атрибут в поле сабформы?

Tags: joomla

Joomla поддерживает XML формы. Вот я одну из таких реализовал, также использовал в ней сабформу. Мне нужно программно изменить атрибут в сабформе. Как это сделать.

genprice.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<form>
    <fieldset name="basic">

        <field name="categories" type="jscategory" required="required" multiple="multiple" /> 
        <field name="attr_polirovka" type="jsextrafield" required="required" default="2"/>

        <field name="prices_material" type="subform" multiple="true"
               layout="joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable-table" buttons="add,remove"
               formsource="administrator/components/com_genprice/models/forms/price.xml" />

        <field name="discount" type="text" required="required" default="30" />

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

price.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<form>
    <field name="polirovka" type="jsattroption" jsattribute="2" required="required" />
    <field name="price" type="text" required="required" default="300000" />
</form>
```

genprice.php

```
public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true)
{
    $form = $this->loadForm(
        'com_getprice.genprice',
        'genprice',
        array(
            'control' => 'jform',
            'load_data' => $loadData
        )
    );

    $input = $prices->setFieldAttribute('prices_material.price', 'jsattroption', '1');

    if (empty($form))
        return false;

    return $form;
}
```

Моя попытка изменить значение атрибута:

```
$input = $prices->setFieldAttribute('prices_material.price', 'jsattroption', '1');
```

Подскажите как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через **setFieldAttribute** мы можем изменить только атрибуты самого поля *prices_material*. Метод setFieldAttribute вызывает метод findGroup (при указание группы полей) и findField в котором есть xpath запрос ('descendant::field[@name="' . $name . '" and not(ancestor::field/form/*)]') - вторая часть которого исключает получение нужного поля, так как поле будет содержать предков field/form (при указание группы полей, там схожий запрос).

Само решение задачи:

```
// Заменяем
// $input = $prices->setFieldAttribute('prices_material.price', 'jsattroption', '1');

// Получаем ссылку на oject(SimpleXMLElement) поля prices_material
$xmlPricesMaterial = $form->getFieldXml('prices_material');

// Ищем в нём дочернее поле price
$element = $xmlPricesMaterial->xpath('form/field[@name="price"]');

// Назначаем атрибут полю price
$element[0]['jsattroption'] = '1';
```